# (React) Render only one child (from props.children) depends of route (location.pathname)

Tags: reactjs, routes, children

Here is my `Switch`:

```
<Switch>
    <Main>
      <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
      <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterForm} />
    </Main>
</Switch>
```

The `Main` Component - is a Wrapper of the Children:

```
class Main extends Component {
     render() {
        const { children } = this.props;

        return (
            ...
            {children}
            ...
        )
     }
}
```

This return me all my (children) components as `LoginForm` as `RegisterForm`

So I need to get only one component depends of the route (`props.location.pathname`)

What is the right solution in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to put 'exact' for the first route tag also. It will solve the problem. As the '/' will get match to all the routes. So to make it specific, you need to put exact for first route as well.

Comment: so now are you still facing the issue? I think now when you have '/' or 'login' as pathname then it will show LoginForm and when you have '/register' then it will show RegisterForm which i think is expected. Is that not happening still?